# how to label a tain_data?

Tags: nlp, cross-validation, multilabel-classification, randomized-algorithms

I have one assignment that I have four files
1) train_data.csv: The training file contains two fields (text, id).
2) train_label.csv: The label file contains two fields (id, label).
3) test_data.csv: The test file contains two fields (text, id).
4) sample_submission.csv: This is a file that needs to be submitted.
And this should be obvious multilabel classification, but whenever I try to identify labels in train data, it doesn't show labels.
How can I remove noise from train_data??
Any type of suggestion welcome!!

train_label:
[image]

train_data:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `The label file contains two fields`? Could you share a sample of your dataset?

Comment: @bkshi yes! i can share

Comment: Do you mean the inner join on *id* between train_data.csv train_label.csv is empty?